# Implement loader in windows form like web application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, desktop-application, showdialog

I'm trying displaying `Loader` while any long running process being executing in `windows forms`. I have implemented code for that, but loader being displayed but not in `CenterParent` location, it will be displayed on Center of the screen.

**Code:**

`CPLoader` is form that I want to display while any process executing.

```
public class CommonLoader
{
    CPLoader cploader = new CPLoader();
    readonly Form form = null;

    public CommonLoader(Form frm)
    {
        form = frm;
    }

    public void ShowLoader()
    {
        try
        {
            if (form.InvokeRequired)
            {
                try
                {
                    cploader = new CPLoader();
                    cploader.ShowDialog();
                }
                catch 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cp loader exception");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Thread th = new Thread(ShowLoader);
                th.IsBackground = false;
                th.Start();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cp loader exception");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// this method will used for hide loader while process stop
    /// </summary>
    public void HideLoader()
    {
        try
        {
            if (cploader != null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                cploader.Invoke(new Action(cploader.Close));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cp loader exception");
        }
    }
}
```

I have also try `cploader.ShowDialog()` with `frm.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate(){cploader.ShowDialog(form); }))`.

If I use `BeginInvoke()` then I'm unable to close the loader.

Comment: By "loader" you mean a splash screen, progress bar or spinning ball? Web applications actually emulate *desktop* applications in that matter. You don't need threads to do this (in fact, threads *can't touch the UI at all*). Just display a *modeless* form with whatever you want to show on top of the current one. This means, just use `Show` instead of `ShowDialog()`, and call `Hide()` when you want to hide it. All the rest of the code will deadlock at worst, or end up running in the UI thread again at best - `BeginInvoke()` means `run this method on the UI thread`

Comment: As for *centering* you didn't post any code that tries to display the form in a specific location, or the form's properties. The only relevant code is `cploader = new CPLoader(); cploader.ShowDialog();` which displays a modal form *without* specifying a parent. This creates a dialog whose parent is the desktop. You should pass the parent form as an argument to either `ShowDialog` or `Show`

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos , I've updated the question please review it

Answer (score 1):

Splash screens, progress screens etc appeared in Visual Basic or Delphi desktop applications long before web applications. They are just modeless forms/windows displayed on top of their application. They don't need threads either - back then applications were mostly single threaded.

Background threads can't modify the UI anyway, which means that the entire `ShowLoader` method does nothing more than try to call :

```
cploader = new CPLoader();
cploader.ShowDialog();
```

All of this can be replaced with

```
public void ShowLoader()
{
    cploader.ShowDialog();
}

public void HideLoader()
{
    cploader.Hide(); 
    //or Close if we don't intend to reuse the loader
}
```

**Specifying the parent**

Calling [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8) without any parameters creates a window whose parent is the desktop. That's why the window appears centered on the screen, not the application.

To specify an owner/parent, just pass it as the `owner` parameter to [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ShowDialog_System_Windows_Forms_IWin32Window_) or [Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=netframework-4.8).

The following code can be used to display a dialog box centered on the current form :

```
var myDialog=new MyDialogForm();
myDialog.ShowDialog(this);
```

This means that `ShowLoader` probably has to accept the owner as a parameter :

```
public void ShowLoader(Form frm)
{
    cploader.ShowDialog(frm);
}
```

**Modeless windows**

`ShowDialog()` is used to display a modal form - a form that retains the focus until it's closed, just like a dialog box. That's why the method is called `ShowDialog()` instead of `ShowModal()`.

A loader needs to be modeless, so `Show` should be used instead :

```
public void ShowLoader(Form frm)
{
    cploader.Show(frm);
}
```

Another difference is that `ShowDialog` returns a result with the user's choice (OK, Cancel etc) while `Show` returns nothing.

**Modal Loader with notification**

If you want to create a modal loader with `ShowDialog` but still perform some work in the background, you need a way to notify that loader from the background thread. You can do that using the [Progress](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) class.

The loader can expose `IProgress<T>` as a property. The `T` parameter can be a simple string or integer showing progress, or a complex entity with progress, a string message and a status indicator. For laziness' sake, let's use `string` and close the dialog if the value is empty :

```
public IProgress<string> Progress{get;private set;}

public CPLoader()
{
    this.Progress=new Progress<string>(UpdateUI);
}

private void UpdateUI(string msg)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(msg))
    {       
        this.DialogResult=DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close(); 
    }
    else
    {
        this.SomeLabel.Text=msg;
    }
}
```

The code that works in the background needs access to that `IProgress<string>` property. Let's say the code that needs to work in the background is :

```
void Work(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        //Do something CPU intensive
        //Report every 1000 items
        if(i%1000==0)
        {
            progress.Report($"{i} out of 1000000");
        }
    }
    //This tells the loader to close.
    progress.Report("");
}
```

This code can run in the background *and* use the loader this way :

```
var loader=new CPLoader();
var task=Task.Run(()=>DoWork(loader.Progress));
loader.ShowDialog();
await task;
```

The loader is initialized first, giving us access to the `IProgress<T>` instance. The job gets started in the background after that with `Task.Run`. When it finishes, it sends an empty progress string and the loader's `UpdateUI` method closed the dialog in response

The code that needs to perform work while loading can access that `IProgress<string>` interface and use it to signal pro

Comment: I think it will block the process until the user will close it.

Comment: I need to show the dialog while the process is executing and after completion of it automatically close without user interaction.

Comment: @HirenPatel why? Did you try it? Even `ShowDialog()` doesn't block the thread, it retains the *focus* on the form. `Show` on the other hand is displayed without preventing the user from working with other controls or forms in the same application

Comment: @HirenPatel besides, that's no different than the loaders you see in web applications. Javascript was single threaded until recently. The loaders you see act as modeless windows themselves. You don't see them blocking their pages though

Comment: Thank @panagiotis-kanavos , let me check

Comment: @HirenPatel this is explained in MSDN, docs, tutorials etc. Unfortunately, many of the MSDN pages for Windows Forms weren't transferred over to the new `learn.microsoft.com` site. [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa984358(v=vs.94)) explains the difference but you'll notice the menu is missing. The [WPF docs on modal vs modeless dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/dialog-boxes-overview) on the other hand are just fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195289/discussion-between-hiren-patel-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: I have tried it,, but cploader.ShowDialog(frm); is throw exception

Comment: @HirenPatel you need `Show()` not ShowDialog. What *did* you try anyway and what exception did you get? Your original code would throw an exception because it tries to display the dialog *from a background thread*. You simply *can't* modify the UI from a background thread. Using a thread was wrong in the first place

Comment: Because I need to show it in the background thread, while my long running process is executing, I want to restrict the user to access the main form by showing loader as a dialog on the main form such as in my code form.

Comment: @HirenPatel no, you *don't* need to do that in the background thread. I repeat, you *can't* do that at all, in any OS - not on Windows or Linux, no matter the language or stack. This isn't a matter of opinion. If you want to restrict the user, use `ShowDialog`.

Comment: @HirenPatel your *original* code was broken to begin with. When `InvokeRequired` returns `true` it means you *have* to use either `Invoke` or `InvokeRequired` to modify the UI. The only way your original code worked is by accident, because the dialog box was owned by the desktop, not the application.

Comment: Can you please provide me a demo for code that helps me. It helps me a lot.

Comment: @HirenPatel as for why no OS allows modifying the UI from another thread, all windowing systems work by posting messages to applications, like button up, down, click, redraw this part of the screen. When you modify the UI you post messages too. Those messages are posted to a message queue and processed by a message pump. Obviously those messages need to be processed in order, otherwise you'd get text painted *before* their background, or up button events processed before the down event. That's why you can't have multiple threads modifying the UI

Comment: @HirenPatel I already posted the code. If you want to display a form that acts like a modal form but *doesn't* block the UI thread, you'll have to use different tricks, like preventing focus change.

Comment: Ok, Thanks yo so much for help.

Comment: A simpler option is to perform any loading work in a background thread - start the work in a background thread with `Task.Run` *before* you display the loader. You can make this a bit smarter if you can tell the loader form to close itself from the background thread using eg the `Progress<T>` class

Comment: actually, for that, I need to make very big changes in my application but now is on production so I can't do that.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your suggestion, let see it works or not .

Comment: @HirenPatel I added an example that can run something in the background and still use `ShowDialog`